# Using declaration to denote a type within a template declaration

Tags: c++, templates, using

I have the following template declaration:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class tree{
public:
tree(int,T2&);
~tree();
...
rNodePtrIter travPreord(int);
void travInord();
rNodePtrIter travInord(int);
void travPostord();
rNodePtrIter travPostord(int);
private:
NodePtrIter hierarchy;
};
```

I declared the type rNodePtrIter just above the template declaration as follows:

```
using rNodePtrIter = list<unique_ptr<node<T1>>>::iterator&;
```

That doesn't compile as the compiler complains that the type T1 is not known:

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'T1'

Is there a way to get in the using declaration as above, so that I could use the alias rNodePtrIter in my template declaration, instead of the longer alternative?

TIA

Vinod

Comment: Don't you think that ought to make `rNodePtrIter` a template as well?

Comment: Why don't you put that type *inside* of a template declaration where `T1` is a type?

Comment: You mean just use list<unique_ptr<node<T1>>>::iterator& rNodePtrIter; inside the template declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move type alias declaration inside of template:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class tree{
public: using rNodePtrIter = typename list<unique_ptr<node<T1>>>::iterator&;
```

Note that it requires `node` template to be already declared.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [*alias template*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
template<typename T1>
using rNodePtrIter = typename list<unique_ptr<node<T1>>>::iterator&;
```

and then replace `rNodePtrIter` inside the class with `rNodePtrIter<T1>`.

Comment: You should probably point out that if he uses this method, `rNodePtrIter` need to be changed to `rNodePtrIter<T1>` inside the class.

Comment: This is actually not going to work because `list<unique_ptr<node<T1>>>::iterator` is dependent type and there is no `typename` infront.

Comment: @VTT ahh, yes, of course. Anyway, the problem should be solved in the way you explained in your answer.